# Ajaxblocks only working for first block

Tags: ajax, javascript

I've installed the Ajaxblocks Module (see https://www.drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks). I have 2 blocks to be loaded by ajax.

The AJAX request looks like this:

```
mywebsite.com/ajaxblocks?blocks=block1/block2
```

The success function looks like this:

```
success: function (data) {
  // Replaces the placeholder divs by the actual block contents returned by the AJAX call,
  // executes the extra JavaScript code and attach behaviours if the apply to the blocks.
  Drupal.freezeHeight();
  for (var id in data) {
      console.log("Worked");
    Drupal.ajaxblocksSetBlockContent(id, data[id]);
  }
  Drupal.unfreezeHeight();
}
```

And the returned json looks like this:

```
{"block1":{"content":"my block content","ajaxblocks_settings":""},"block2":{"content":"my second block content","ajaxblocks_settings":""}}
```

Now only the first block is loaded. Why is this? The for-loop doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bugreport, and bugreports should be posted in issue queue, not here.